# ROS2: urdf not copied to install folder

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS2 Foxy (on Ubuntu 20.04LTS Desktop)

Problem: urdf directory in package not being copied to the install folder
Error Msg:

```
InvalidLaunchFileError: Caught exception when trying to load file of format [py]: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ubuntu/handsonros2/install/rviz2_basics/share/rviz2_basics/urdf/gopigoMinimal.urdf'
```

Package Tree: ~/handsonros2/src/chap3rviz2_basics/

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── launch
│   ├── ros1_gopigoMinimal_rviz.launch.donotuse
│   ├── ros1_gopigoMinimal_rviz_simple.launch.donotuse
│   └── ros2_gpgMin_rviz2_simple.launch.py
├── package.xml
├── README.md
├── ros1CMakeLists.txt
├── ros1package.xml
├── ros2CMakeLists.txt
├── ros2package.xml
├── rviz
│   ├── default.rviz
│   ├── gopigoMinimal.rviz
│   └── gpgMin.rviz2.rviz
├── setup.py
└── urdf
    ├── gopigoMinimal.urdf
    └── keith_gpg.urdf
```

setup.py:

```
import os
from glob import glob
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import find_packages

package_name = 'rviz2_basics'

setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=[package_name],
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
            ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
        (os.path.join('share', package_name), glob('launch/*.py)),
        (os.path.join('share', package_name), glob('urdf/*'))
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    maintainer='slowrunner',
    maintainer_email='slowrunner@users.noreply.github.com',
    description='ROS2 Version of Hands-On ROS - Chap4 RVIZ Basics',
    license='Apache License 2.0',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    # entry_points={
    #     'console_scripts': [
    #     ],
    },
)
```

package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>rviz2_basics</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>ROS2 Version of Hands-On ROS - Chap4 RVIZ Basics"</description>
  <maintainer email="slowrunner@users.noreply.github.com">slowrunner</maintainer>
  <license>Apache License 2.0</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <exec_depend>robot_state_publisher</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>joint_state_publisher</exec_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381403/ros2:-urdf-not-copied-to-install-folder/) by [RobotDreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/40559/robotdreams/) on ROS Answers with karma: 327 on 2021-06-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like setup.py was a red herring.  I initially created the package with:

```
ros2 pkg create rviz2_basics
```

which created package.xml and CMakeLists.txt.

Then added dependencies to package.xml

```
  <exec_depend>robot_state_publisher</exec_depend>  
  <exec_depend>joint_state_publisher</exec_depend>
```

Added launch files installation in the CMakeLists.txt

```
# (Always add before ament_package() line)
# Install launch files
install(DIRECTORY
  launch
  DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}/
</pre>
but did not at that time understand I also needed:
<pre>
# Install urdf files
install(DIRECTORY
  urdf
  DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}/
```

and started following the urdf-tutorial which creates a setup.py to satisfy the urdf, but it turned out all my efforts with setup.py were not actually being used.

Solution was to edit the CMakeLists.txt and add the urdf files installation.

---

Originally posted by [RobotDreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/40559/robotdreams/) with karma: 327 on 2021-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make a modification in your launch file. Your other files are fine. Your `setup.py` will result the urdf files to be copied and not the directory like this: `/home/ubuntu/handsonros2/install/rviz2_basics/share/rviz2_basics/gopigoMinimal.urdf`
You can confirm if the file exists on this path by cd'ing into it.

If you'd like the syntax for reference, you can refer to [this package](https://github.com/benbongalon/ros2-urdf-tutorial/tree/master/urdf_tutorial).

---

Originally posted by [trunc8](https://answers.ros.org/users/44889/trunc8/) with karma: 156 on 2021-06-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RobotDreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/40559/robotdreams/) on 2021-06-29**:
That (urdf-tutorial) was what led me to add the setup.py in the first place.  I originally created the package as a cmake which didn't include a setup.py or setup.cfg.

I deleted the build and install directories, and rebuilt - share/rviz2_basics/launch gets created with the launch files, but for some reason the urdf folder does not get created, (nor is the gopigoMinimal.urdf copied anywhere - did not get copied to share/rviz2_basics )

I added a setup.cfg file and tried again, no cigars - still launch folder but no urdf folder no urdf file.

I think I might see the problem - in CMakeLists.txt the install for the launch folder instructions exist, but not the urdf folder.  I'll try adding that and see what happens.

**Comment by [trunc8](https://answers.ros.org/users/44889/trunc8/) on 2021-06-29**:
Yeah! CMakeLists and setup.py shouldn't be existing together. I missed them in your directory structure entirely! Your obervations in the other answer are correct. Cheers!